# Automatically install build dependencies prior to building an RPM package

Tags: fedora, rpm

I am trying to build the .rpm package. i have just followed the steps to do that. Till now all step was gone fine but now i just stuck with this step. I just ran the following command and got this error :

```
rpmbuild -ba asterisk.spec
error: Failed build dependencies: 
    gtk2-devel is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    libsrtp-devel is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    gmime22-devel is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    graphviz is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    graphviz-gd is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    latex2html is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    neon-devel is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    libical-devel is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    speex-devel >= 1.2 is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    gsm-devel is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    libedit-devel is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    openais-devel is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    alsa-lib-devel is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    dahdi-tools-devel >= 2.0.0 is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    dahdi-tools-libs >= 2.0.0 is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    libpri-devel >= 1.4.12 is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    libss7-devel >= 1.0.1 is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    spandsp-devel >= 0.0.5-0.1.pre4 is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    iksemel-devel is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    jack-audio-connection-kit-devel is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    libresample-devel is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    lua-devel is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    mISDN-devel is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    bluez-libs-devel is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    libtool-ltdl-devel is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    unixODBC-devel is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    portaudio-devel >= 19 is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    postgresql-devel is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    radiusclient-ng-devel is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    net-snmp-devel is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    lm_sensors-devel is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    freetds-devel is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
    uw-imap-devel is needed by asterisk-1.8.12.2-1.fc15.x86_64
```

I am using fedora-15. How to resolve this error?
Any idea and suggestion will be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install these devel packages,

```
yum -y install alsa-lib-devel bluez-libs-devel dahdi-tools-devel dahdi-tools-libs freetds-devel gmime22-devel graphviz graphviz-gd gsm-devel gtk2-devel iksemel-devel jack-audio-connection-kit-devel latex2html libedit-devel libical-devel libpri-devel libresample-devel libsrtp-devel libss7-devel libtool-ltdl-devel lm_sensors-devel lua-devel mISDN-devel neon-devel net-snmp-devel openais-devel portaudio-devel postgresql-devel radiusclient-ng-devel spandsp-devel speex-devel unixODBC-devel uw-imap-devel
```

If this package belongs to standard repository, use `yum-builddep XXX` instead. (need to install `yum-utils` first)

Comment: Can i install this packages during installation of rpm? i want to preinstall all the dependency.

Comment: @juned those are required for building the binary RPM, not installing it. Yum can handle resolving depends on installation.

Comment: @jordanm i can resolve this error by installing this missing packages in my system but what if i run same rpn package in other system.

Comment: @Warlock can i install those dependencies using spec file. i want to pre-install all those dependency. like if we install asterisk using `yum install asterisk` then why it doesn't give this kind of error and automatically installs dependencies

Comment: @juned build dependencies are not needed for you to run an application, but for you to build an app

Comment: so how do i achieve this,while running `rpm -ivh My_RPM_PKG` its should not give me any error regarding dependencies rather it should install them automatically.

Comment: @warl0ck in my `asterisk.spec` file all dependencies are mentioned like this `BuildRequires: libsrtp-devel` so where should i put the source of this dependecy.

Comment: Though this is a very old question/answer, it's worth noting that `dnf` can (and as I recall `yum` could, as well) work off a specfile, for build deps. Regardless whether the package being built is already present in a standard repo, `dnf builddep $PACKAGE.spec` is the simplest way to install all of the  build deps required to build _$PACKAGE_.